# Using Intellij With Remote Server

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2016

I have a dev *nix box. For most cases I can just ssh into the box and use emacs to develop. However, as I've started doing more Java work with very large codebases, I've realized IntelliJ IDEA is pretty invaluable.

Problem: I would like to use IntelliJ IDEA on OS X, but work with a project located on some other machine. Is there a way to configure IntelliJ IDEA to do this? (over ssh/mosh/or whatever)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up just using IntelliJ locally and pointing it to a mounted server drive.

Comment: I usually develop in my workstation, but sometimes I want to work off my laptop. It is a hassle to set up my laptop environment for the build, indexing etc. Is it possible to leave the indexing etc on my workstation?

Comment: This is how I was developing for 2 years with notepad++; pretty ideal but lacks the conveniences of intelliJ. But now I'm trying to use intellij, the software targets a linux server but obviously I code in windows... so it's like intelliJ isn't designed to handle the situation... I've kind of been able to trick the idea into thinking some of my references like termcolor are correct (they are at the target, the mounted srv drive)... but had issues with python2.7 ssl pip... gave up. thinking its back to notepad++ unless someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "project" you actually mean the application that is running on a remote box? In IntelliJ IDEA, there's an option for [remote server configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html). It is also possible to [edit individual files at remote hosts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/editing-individual-files-on-remote-hosts.html) if that's a requirement.

Comment: Yes. I mean an "intellij" project. I'd like it to retain all indexing features, etc... but it would need to operate on that remote server.

Comment: Try running x11 sever on remote machine and run intellij on the remote machine from Osx using xquartz.