# How to develop my project remotely using IntellijIDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, remote-desktop

I want to work remotely on my project but my project files are on the other machine in my office. I don't want to use Desktop Sharing because it uses a lot of traffic and it is slow. I want to work with my LOCAL intellij but files would serve from my computer in office. Is there any approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Intellij With Remote Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167724/using-intellij-with-remote-server)

Comment: If you use Windows, you could probably use OneDrive to do this.  Or, depending on your company's policies, you could keep your source code in a repository that is accessible via the internet (e.g. BitBucket or GitHub).

Comment: Given the amount of IO operations InteliJ performs on the files, accessing them remotely (like from a shared network drive or the like) is asking for trouble, especially if your network connection is slow enough for it to be a factor. Add unpredictable disconnections caued by VPN restart and the like, and you'll quickly lose any productivity advantage modern IDE has to offer. I strongly recommend copying files into local computer and using git for version control and synchronization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will work, IntelliJ is built around the idea that the files are on the local drive, and if its a descent project it still will be slow.
Depending on your security settings, internet speed, etc.

You can try the following:

1. At work create a network drive that stores the code and on your local computer map this drive, so intelliJ will "think" that its a regular File System but in fact the files will be stored remotely. I personally believe that it will be really slow, but you can try, this is the closest answer to your question I believe.
2. Use X Server and stream the graphics from the intelliJ that runs on your server at work  to your local PC. In such a setup the computer at work will run the intelliJ process and all the files will be stored there too. Your Local PC will show the graphics. Usually this works when you have linux at work, I do this sometimes with programs like MobaXTerm, probably there are others
3. Connect to you computer with remote desktop on Windows - as you say its slow but its still a solution, probably faster internet can solve the issue :)
4. By far the best option I can recommend: Use git's distributed nature. Assuming your project is managed by git (and if it isn't - consider using source control anyway).
   Then checkout the copy of the project from... Here are two options:

Option a: ...from the remote central repository that hosts the source files of your project in your organization

Option b: ... from your computer at work, you can define in git the "remote source" (this question is not about git, I know but you can use (`git remote add <your computer at work>` + chose the protocol that will work for you best: ssh, git internal protocol, http, etc)

Then you'll compile the project locally (you might have to install build tools like maven, gradle, etc. on your local computer and then by using your locally installed IDE you will be able to develop fast. Now when you're ready to "submit" your code - you can push it upstream. In the option A it will be the remote repo like you probably already do at work,  with option B you will push to remote branch on your computer at work.
This will be pretty fast and I used to work like this a lot of times.